# Populate child entity when creating new parent in LINQ to SQL

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

I have setup a LINQ to SQL DataContext to reflect a basic set of relationships:

An appointment has one client, one employee and many AppointmentServices. Each AppointmentService has one ServiceDefinition. Each is linked to the other by a primary and foreign key.

[image: LINQ to SQL relationships]

I create a new appointment in memory, populate the clientID and employeeID. I create an AppService in memory and add the AppService to the entity set in tmpAppointment.AppServices.

```
tmpAppointment = New Appointment
tmpAppointment.ClientID = 1
tmpAppointment.EmployeeID = 2

tmpAppService = New AppService
tmpAppService.ServiceDefinitionID = 123

tmpAppointment.AppServices.Add(tmpAppService)
```

Is it possible to populate the ServiceDefinition of each AppService in memory WITHOUT inserting either the appointment or the app service into their respective databases? The user may cancel this process and I simply wanted to avoid adding then deleting from the database unnecessarily.

I could tee all this up after confirming the user wants to go ahead using unbound controls, but I wondered if LINQ to SQL provides a more elegant solution.

I have tried:

`tmpAppointment.AppServices.Load`

and

creating a `new ServiceDefinition` then populating it and then adding it to AppServices

and

selecting the correct ServiceDefinition from the DB and adding it to the AppServices entityset

The first does nothing and the latter two throw the following from within the DataContext class:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains more than one element'

at the auto-generated line

```
<Global.System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AssociationAttribute _
    (Name:="AppService_ServiceDefinition", Storage:="_AppServices", _
    ThisKey:="ServiceID", OtherKey:="ServiceDefinitionID", _
    IsForeignKey:=true)>

Public Property AppService() As AppService
Get
    Return Me._AppServices.Entity
End Get

Set
    Dim previousValue As AppService = Me._AppServices.Entity <<<< error thrown
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of assinging the ID, you need to assign the entire entity.

```
tmpAppService.ServiceDefinitionID = 123
```

becomes

```
tmpAppSerice.ServiceDefinition = someServiceDefinition
```

This way, it will all be inserted at the same time and linq-2-sql handles the setting and assignment of the proper ID's

Comment: Thank you, however doing so throws the error I mentioned. I have updated my question with more detail on that front.

Comment: I solved my error throwing problem. Once I did that, I was allowed to manually populate the ServiceDefinition entity. Thank you. To anyone else having this problem, LINQ to SQL does work as you expect it to, but you need to have your associations set up correctly. Once I changed my Parent/Child relationships to basically be the opposite of what I originally had (ref diagram at the top), things started to work properly - funny that!